# Connection closed error when working with large files on AWS S3 using ballerinax/aws.s3

Tags: amazon-s3, ballerina

I am performing a (client side) copy using `s3->getObject` and `s3->createObject` using streams. For *smaller files it works well*. However, **for larger files the connection closes** at around the 1 min. mark, with the following error:

> error: Connection between client and remote host is closed

I have tried playing around with the `timeout` config param but it doesn't help at all.

Sample code:

```
import ballerinax/aws.s3;
import ballerina/io;

public function main() returns error? {

    s3:Client 'client = check new ({
        accessKeyId: "xxx",
        secretAccessKey: "xxx",
        region: "ap-southeast-2",
        timeout: 0
    });

    stream<byte[], io:Error?> s = check 'client->getObject("xxx", "xxx");

    var s1 = stream from var x in s
        select x.cloneReadOnly();    // is there a better way to do this? convert stream of byte[] to stream of block

    check 'client->createObject("xxx", "xxx", s1);
    io:println("completed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we don't specify the timeout, the default value will be 60.
I could reproduce this issue with a 19 MB file.
But after increased the timeout to 120, it worked fine.

Please increase the timeout according to your file size and try.